# Python - YahooTickerDownloader Not returning any tickers

Tags: python

I have been using [YahooTickerDownlaoder.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Yahoo-ticker-downloader/) for many months now, but for some reason, it does not return any tickers anymore. I have searched for common problems and even downloaded the latest version of this program but have been unsuccessful to get it to work.

The program loops through the alphabet to search and store tickers from yahoo finance: `https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup/?bypass=true&s=a&r=&m=ALL&t=S&b=0`

I tried to opening the link on my browser, but it does not return any list of tickers/companies anymore. Is this program basically terminated? I would like to fix the program so I can start using it again and any help is appreciated.

[image]